# Removing "uninteresting" segments of data to make model fit better

Tags: dataset

**The data:** Daily percentage of time spent watching TV. Data from 25 people.

**The model:** Regression on response variable using covariate effects and random effects.

**Question:**

4 of the people present in the data do not watch TV at all during a regular week. There are only positive values during the weekends. Is it all right to omit these 4 people from the data, so that a model can be fitted on the data? Otherwise, there's too many zeroes for my model to handle.

Could I delete them based on the argument "we want to study the people who regularly watch TV, and what their tendencies are. These 4 people do not regularly watch TV, and therefore we are not interested in their behavior"?

Is there perhaps some other model I can fit on data prior to by main model which I can use to formally disregard these patients?

For example, I was thinking of using logistic regression where I average the percentages of every patient from an entire week, and then encode it as either "0" or "1" if its lower or higher than some set limit. Then I perform logistic regression using the people as a factor, and then we disregard all people that has some low estimated probability (again, low in terms of a  fixed limit)?

Answer (score 1):

Your original question does not seem to be about people who regularly watch TV, why would you change the question just because your model is having trouble? It seems more rational to change the model. Additionally, this is an outcome dependent subgroup definition, which is always problematic. What if these people just had a busy week at work and normally watch lots of TV during the week? Then they might well be "regular TV watchers" by most reasonable definitions and you just happened to get a outcome realization that had them not watching much.

I am uncertain why you would have trouble fitting a random effects logistic regression (or some other model such as a zero inflated Poisson model or something similar to actually also model how much TV they watch) with perhaps covariates for weekday versus weekend day (which perhaps should be subject specific random effects, because people might not just differ in how much TV they watch, but also their probability of watching any during the week)? Then you can describe people as in terms of how likely they are to watch TV during the week versus on the weekend, how much they watch, if they do etc.

Comment: "Why would you change the question just because your model is having trouble" .... uhh ... so I can at least get SOME answers instead of NO answers? Use your brain ...not everyone one of us is a full-blood statistician, I am just a student, and can only fit the models in the curricilum.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting some data because it lies outside the range studied was a primary cause of the Challenger disaster, as Feynman discovered. If NASA had analyzed the loss of O-rings across the full range of temperatures, they would have noticed a significant correlation.

When you ask "Is there perhaps some other model I can fit on data prior to by main model which I can use to formally disregard these patients?", you appear to ask for a method, ignoring the more important question whether you should disregard this data in the first place. This is especially worrisome since you have a small population (~25) of highly varied subjects (humans).